# why does rect.intersect shrink my rectangle

Tags: java, android, bitmap

(I use Android studio 3.0.1 for this code)
I would like my player to bounce off a wall and my bullet to destroy when hitting a wall and to detect this collision I wrote (for the player collision) the following code:

```
boolean checkCollision(Rect playerrect) {
    for (Wall w : walls) {
        if (playerrect.intersect(w.getRectangle())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem I am having is that if I use the ".intersect" the first one in the statement, so in this case the player, it's Bitmap shrinks to like a thin black line. If I write the code like:

```
w.getRectangle().intersect(playerrect)
```

the Bitmap of the wall shrinks. This means that the problem doesn't lie within the bouncing code of the wall but in the ".intersect" checking. I use rectangles for the objects to detect collision and scale the Bitmap around that rectangle. Does any of you guys know how this is possible or should I use another method to check collisions of two .jpg Bitmaps?

Comment: because it works like [that](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Rect.java#432)

Comment: Try `Rect.intersects(playerrect, w.getRectangle())`

Comment: Thanks to d.j.brown I started using:

    (w.getRectangle().intersects(rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom)). Now it works